# Sul significato di "R" in "R. QUESTURA" in un fonogramma del 1943

Tags: grammar, meaning, abbreviations

C'è qualcuno che sa cosa significhi quella erre puntata ("R.") prima di "QUESTURA" nel fonogramma—risalente al 1943—rappresentato qui sotto?

[image]

Forse 'rispettabile'?

Prego indicare qualche fonte attendibile, non si accettano opinioni.

Comment: L'abbreviazione era molto comune: *R. Esercito*, *R. Università*, *RR. Carabinieri* e così via. È l'analogo di *k.u.k.* (Austria-Ungheria) o *k.k.* (Austria).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sta per "Regia": "Regia Questura" era la dicitura completa all'epoca, è sufficiente [una ricerca su Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=regia+questura)   per rintracciare trascrizioni e fotografie di documenti di epoca fascista (o anteriore) che riportano la dicitura abbreviata o per esteso.